# Accepting TextClipping with NSImageView Drop Box

Tags: objective-c, macos, text, osx-mountain-lion, nsimageview

[image]

If you drag and drop a selection of text onto a folder, you will get a file with an extension of **textClipping**.  **TextEdit**'s document window accepts a text selection.  Many applications do accept textClipping.  How do you receive a text selection on an **NSImageView** drop box?  The regular operation of **performDragOperation** doesn't appear to accept a selection of text.

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSArray *urls;
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType]) {
        urls = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSURL class]] options:nil];
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate];
    ...
    ...

    return YES;
}
```

These lines of code let me accept files, but not textClipping.  What is the secret of accepting textClipping?  Maybe, you can't accept it with NSImageView?  Running a search with 'Objective-C textClipping' turns up nothing.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Text clippings are either strings or attributed strings (if the contents contain rich text).
To read those objects from the pasteboard you have to search for `NSStringPboardType` or `NSRTFPboardType` respectively.

`NSStringPboardType` can be read as `NSString`.
`NSRTFPboardType` can be read as `NSAttributedString`.

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard* pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray* pboardContents = nil;
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType])
    {
        pboardContents = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSURL class]] options:nil];
    }
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSStringPboardType])
    {
        pboardContents = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSString class]] options:nil];
    }
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSRTFPboardType])
    {
        pboardContents = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSAttributedString class]] options:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Pasteboard contents:%@", pboardContents);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, weichsel.  An NSImageView drop box with this code doesn't appear to accept a text drop.  What am I doing wrong, do you know?

Comment: Actually, it seems that I can just use an NSTextView control to accept a text drop.